# datatable not submitting whole data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have following table:

```
<form:form action="buyStock" method="post" modelAttribute="orderList" 
onsubmit="myFunction" >       
<table  id="buyTable" class="display" >
  <thead>
  <tr>
<th>Stock Symbol</th>
<th>Stock Name</th>
<th>Last Trade</th>
<th>Gains</th>
```

I make it into a datatable using the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

 buyTable =$("#buyTable").DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 2,
    "aLengthMenu": [[100, 25, 50, 100,  -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
   });
```

The problem is if the user wants to buy multiple stocks, it will only send over the stock in the current page, nothing the user has selected beforehand,

I tried to use the following function to solve the issue but to no success:

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    buyTable.search('').draw(false);
}
```

How do I submit the whole form and not only what is just visible?

Comment: if it is not a single page, save your date into localstorage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp then retrieve when you submit

Comment: or store it in localStorage or sessionStoreage as he/she suggested but instead of submit, pull it all out and send it as an ajax call